# Mean Face Matlab

Tags: matlab

anyone has an idea how I can do crop a traingulacion it looks like in this picture : https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTg9-xXE-xzqKmQoVCi3b3AkeDCrA0k56d1xm8ohoddenz8lXuqYw , and I have the points:

```
tri = delaunay (data2 (:, 1), data2 (:, 2));
imshow (I9) hold ('on');
scatter (data2 (:, 1), data2 (:, 2), 'SizeData', 10, 'MarkerFaceColor', 'w');
r9 = triplot (tri, data2 (:, 1), data2 (:, 2), 'w');
```

thank

Comment: No men, sorry is like this : https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTg9-xXE-xzqKmQoVCi3b3AkeDCrA0k56d1xm8ohoddenz8lXuqYw, because my tringulation is like this... – Dramon

Answer (score 1):

here's a [hint](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inpolygon.html), try:

```
doc inpolygon
```

Comment: No men, sorry is like this : https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTg9-xXE-xzqKmQoVCi3b3AkeDCrA0k56d1xm8ohoddenz8lXuqYw, because my tringulation is like this...